# PHP, addressing objects using class

Tags: php, json, class, object, instantiation

I,m trying to list all the names from a  json database to html using a class. the html output should look something like this:-

> **Characters**
>
> - name: John
> - name: Sarah
> - name: Michael

I've managed to reach this far with my code. I know this code is not finished or it is has errors but I'm still a beginner and learning. Can you please help me get this code to work?

**Json database file**

> databas.json

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "name": "John",
        "height": "182 cm",
        "mass": "80 kg",
    },
    {
        "name": "Sarah",
        "height": "165 kg",
        "mass": "60 cm",
    },
    {
        "name": "Michael",
        "height": "178 cm",
        "mass": "75 kg",
    },
    ]
}
```

**Index file**

> index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

        <title>Character</title>

    </head>

    <body style="margin-bottom:20em;">
        <h1>Characters</h1>
            <?php include('characters.php'); ?>

            <?php 
            $data = file_get_contents("databas.json");
            $data = json_decode($data, true);

            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($data);
            echo '</pre>';

            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Class code**

> characters.php

```
<?php

class Character {

        private $name;

public function __construct($name) {
            $this->name = $name;

        }
public function getName($name){
        return $this->name;
        }

}
 ?>
```

> The $data content are

```
Array
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => John
                    [height] => 182 cm
                    [mass] => 80 kg
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Sarah
                    [height] => 165 kg
                    [mass] => 60 cm
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Michael
                    [height] => 178 cm
                    [mass] => 75 kg
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Can you share the content of `$data`? (use `var_dump($data)`)

Comment: I just added it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I get you rigth but you can do simple `foreach` loop:

```
$data = file_get_contents("databas.json");
$data = json_decode($data, true);

foreach($data["result"] as $e) {
    echo "Name: " . $e["name"];
}
```

Notice that send `true` in `json_decode` return associative array so you can access the name key with `[key]` so no need in `include('characters.php');`

**Edit**: If you want to use the class:

```
foreach($data["result"] as $e) {
    $character = new Character($e["name"]);
    $characters[] = $character;
}

foreach($characters as $character) {
    echo "Name: " . $character->getName();
}
```

Comment: I know it is possible but I'm trying to use class to do it.

Comment: @DhulfiqarH.Al-Hussan then you need to load your array to class before - updated my answer

Comment: can you suggest how to do it?

Comment: Should I write this inside the class file?

Comment: No, inside the `index.php` - I still do not understand why you want to use Character class... (maybe XY problem?)

Comment: I'm supposed to understand how to use Class to access data in the json file. I used your code and didn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand exactly what you need... Why are you trying to use the class and not echo as associative array?

Comment: I need to adress all the names in the JSON file by using a class, then echo the addressed names and output them to be seen in the html.

Comment: **Why** you want to use the class?

Comment: For the sake of learning how the class work. For example what would happen if i choose private or protected instead of public. It is a school project.

Comment: In that case: insert the first `foreach` loop to construct the Characters object after the `json_decode` to build array of object. Then iterate over that array (second `foreach`) and use class method `getName` to echo the name. Notice the `getName` function should not get the `$name` as input argument - as it is a getter function - you may want to remove it. 
If you still has some issue with the code please comment what not working and what error/ notice did it showed

Comment: I don't know but didn't you already suggest that in your edit in answer? I did it and it did not work. I'm so lost in this. Do you know any way to show the errors in the code?

Comment: I did suggest that - does the construct character loop finish fine? (you can echo something after to check) and do `var_dump($characters)` to see what the array contains

Comment: sorry i had a typo.. var_dumb($characters) shows this: array(3) { [0]=> object(Character)#1 (1) { ["name":"Character":private]=> string(4) "John" } [1]=> object(Character)#2 (1) { ["name":"Character":private]=> string(5) "Sarah" } [2]=> object(Character)#3 (1) { ["name":"Character":private]=> string(7) "Michael" } }

Comment: When I use print_r($e["name"]), I get only Michael's name, do you know why that happens?

Comment: I am guessing you using `print_r($e["name"]` after the loop - so you only get the last element. After creating the array you need to loop again if you want to get all the names

Comment: Yes, that was correct.. I added it to the loop and it works now. You was really helpful.. thanks for your time.

Comment: I did, but it says that i need 15 reputation for it to be visible or something like that.

Comment: @Dhulfiqar - you need 15 reputation for up-vote an answer. There is no reputation limit for marking it as accepted - (the grey "v' mark at the left of the post) - this signal for other that the post solve your issue

Comment: Found it! ... Done!